# Java: is there a way to create a constructor in an inner private class?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I am wondering if there's a way to build a constructor for an inner private class that implements Iterator.

```
public class Outer
{
  public Outer
  {

  }

  public Iterator<Item> iterator()
  {
     return new Inner();
  }

  private class Inner implements Iterator<Item>
  {
     // how to build a constructor for this inner class ??
     public Item next()
     public boolean hasNext()
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, This is what the collections libraries do. What is your doubt?

Answer (score 2):

You literally just create a constructor within the inner class, like the following does:

```
     public Inner() {
          //Do stuff.
     }
```

Have you tried to do this?